# Can a JVM be configured so a browser will run only trusted applets?

Tags: browser, applet, jvm, signed

Is there browser and JVM combination that can be configured such that ONLY signed Applets will run? The purpose is to ensure that Applets must be authenticated before they are executed, even if they only access safe APIs.

Comment: There is no way I know of for implementing this functionality.  What is the reason for the 'purpose'?

Comment: It was to allow an enterprise or business to block untrusted applets. Bugs in the JVM can mean that the Java sandbox is "leaky" and hence can present a potential security risk.